# Dotnet not found error when generating Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab-ci pipeline that should *automatically generate* a Dockerfile for a given .Net Core project if it does not already exist and after that execute a docker build.

I am getting an error when attempting to generate the Dockerfile :

```
section_end:1657538312:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1657538312:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/demo/devops/labs/.git/
[32;1mCreated fresh repository.[0;m
[32;1mChecking out c2e2d044 as ingress...[0;m
[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1657538314:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1657538314:download_artifacts
[0K[0K[36;1mDownloading artifacts[0;m[0;m
[32;1mDownloading artifacts for publish_job (36805)...[0;m
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok      [0;m  id[0;m=36805 responseStatus[0;m=200 OK token[0;m=-1ETTroN
section_end:1657538315:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1657538315:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[32;1m$ dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY[0;m
/scripts-1175-36806/step_script: eval: line 118: dotnet: not found
section_end:1657538316:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1657538316:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1657538316:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 127
[0;m
```

However the dotnet command executes well in the publish stage. I am not sure why dotnet is not being recognized in the docker context.

The pipeline:

```
before_script:


 - 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'


build_job:
  tags:
    - labs
  only:
    - develop
    - ingress
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore


publish_job:
  tags:
    - labs
  only:
    - develop
    - ingress
  stage: publish
  artifacts:
      name: "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      paths:
        - ./$PUBLISH_DIR
  script:
    - dotnet publish ./src --configuration Release --output $(pwd)/$PUBLISH_DIR

docker_build_dev:
  tags:
    - labs
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.6.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  only:
    - develop
    - ingress
  stage: docker
  script: |
    echo "checking dockerfile existence"
    if ! [ -e Dockerfile ]; then 
    echo "dockerfile doesn't exist. Trying to create a new dockerfile from csproj."
    docker_entrypoint=$(grep -m 1 AssemblyName ./src/*.csproj | sed -r 's/\s*<[^>]*>//g' | sed -r 's/\r$//g').dll
    cat > Dockerfile << EOF
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
    RUN dotnet --version
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./publish .
    
    ENTRYPOINT dotnet $docker_entrypoint
    EOF
    echo "dockerfile created"
    else
    echo "dockerfile exists"
    fi
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

> eval: line 118: dotnet: not found

It looks like you haven't defined an `image:` for this job and whatever default image you are using does not have `dotnet` installed (or if you're using a shell runner, your runner system does not have dotnet installed/on PATH).

To address this, you should either (1) specify an `image:` that has dotnet available (or install it on your runner if using a shell runner and ensure it is on PATH) or (2) install dotnet as part of your job.

For example:

```
myjob:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk
  # ...
```

Alternatively, you can use a [dotnet install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) to install dotnet in your job.