# Gitlab CI On Prem, Docker Image and ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a .NET 6 application. We added CI using:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --no-restore'
```

From https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/dotnetcore/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

But we have an error:

> dotnet command not found

I have tried with shared and custom linux runner but the same error keeps appearing.

Comment: The version misalignment issue is mentioned in the link you provided. Obviously you have this problem, your application is .NET6, but the SDK is 7.0. Check this: [Target .NET 7 and Fix .NET Version Misalignment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/dotnetcore/-/commit/2ccddd1d4d85644db2e22bb42a038aa88bde54bf).

Comment: In addition, [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62208#issuecomment-989232113) mentions that you need to create a symlink using the following command: `ln -sf /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet` in .net6. I'm not sure if this is your environment, but it might help.

Comment: If this error persists, you can use a [dotnet install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) to install dotnet in your job. Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72942919/18789859).

Comment: @Chen I am sorry but I do use dotnet 6. Updated question.

Comment: I think I need to use Docker runner executor. We have currently shell executor.

Answer (score 1):

Take this. It will build you Docker image and push it into you Docker Hub image repository. Do not forget to create `REGISTRY_USER` and `REGISTRY_PASS` to login to DockerHub under `project/settings/"CI/CD"/Variables`.

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: 'src/DemoApp/'
  IMAGE_NAME: "your-account/demo-app"
  IMAGE_TAG: "1.0"
  
cache:
  # Per-stage and per-branch caching.
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'

  policy: pull-push
before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore src/DemoApp/DemoApp.csproj --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'

build_image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - private
  image: docker:24.0.0-rc.4-cli
  services:
    - docker:24.0.0-rc.4-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG

tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - private
  script:
    - 'dotnet test src/DemoApp/DemoApp.csproj --no-restore'
```